# Automatic toyota 2002 premio car straining noise

Tags: toyota

i drive an automatic toyota premio car and it makes a straining noise as it picks up speed and but normalizes when i slow down. What could be causing this?

Comment: Could you pin pint where the noise is coming from? It is coming from the centre of the car? I had the same problem in a 2009 corolla and the culprit was the exhaust shield where the exhaust pipe connects to the engine. Check that to see it is lose.

Answer (score 0):

A straining noise that gets consistently louder in pitch and/or volume as the car gets faster is usually a sign of a worn bearing in a wheel or it could be a problem in the differential (rear wheel drive) or transaxle (front wheel drive). As the car moves faster the wheels and the mechanisms that drive the wheels spin faster making the bearings move faster, and the bad bearing makes a louder or higher pitches noise.

It could also be a piece of road junk that has gotten wedged in a wheel well or a piece of material from the car itself that is rubbing, as the wheels move faster there's more rubbing and more noise.

If the car is pulling one way or the other you could have a stuck brake on the side it is pulling to, it's also possible you have a stuck emergency brake. Those are less likely scenarios.

Where the noise is coming from will give you the best clue, wherever the noise is is where the problem is. If it seems to be coming from a particular wheel then that's what needs to be checked. If it seems to be coming from the middle-front of the car then it's probably in the transaxle or CV joint.